# Mikrotik + Freeradius + Mikrotik-Address-List

Tags: networking, mysql, pptp, freeradius

I have Mikrotik which works like PPTP server and Freeradius for authentication and authorization.

How to assign PPTP user's IP or name in Freeradius (user1 = 10.11.1.145 in my case) with Mikrotik's firewall group?
I need all this stuff because Firewall groups helps to deal with rules better.

I've tried to add this record to the `radreply` table

```
INSERT INTO radius.radreply (username, attribute, op, value) VALUES ('user1', 'Mikrotik-Address-List', ':=', 'remote_managers');
```

but without results.

After user1 was connected to Mikrotik there is a record in Log that MT-Address-List="remote_managers" but it doesn't appear in Firewall>Address List.

Answer (score 0):

Did you refer 'Mikrotik's firewall group' to 'Mikrotik User Group' ?

If so, find the way to make freeradius give 'reply:Mikrotik-Group' in response.

Please read https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:RADIUS_Client#Access-Accept

I'm also playing with FreeRadius and Mikrotik, but I take the 'rest' path rather then 'unlang'.
Nothing wrong with unlang (it's the default), just make sure you realy know how to read-set some attributes with it.

Comment: What do you mean speaking "Did you refer 'Mikrotik's firewall group' to 'Mikrotik User Group'" ? I don't need User Groups, my need is such schema: When user user1 (for example) connects to Mikrotik's PPTP server, router puts user's ip address to firewall address list "remote_managers". I know that it's possible but I can not implement that in practice.

Comment: Refering to https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:RADIUS_Client#Access-Accept it would be MIKROTIK_ADDRESS_LIST attribute.

Comment: Next interesting thing is Mikrotik understand 'Mikrotik-Address-List' value https://i.imgur.com/z0C4T4k.jpg but new address list doesn't appear in firewall.

Comment: @Newbie21231, what if you pre-define an address list called 'remote_managers' (maybe need 1 fake IP) ? Maybe the access-accept part of mikrotik's radius clients only able to 'add' the IP to existing address list and cant 'create new address list'.

Comment: Yep, I understand you clearly. I've try such conditions couple days ago but with no luck.